Make a property required based on other property's value
I'm working on a usecase where I need to enforce a set of object keys based on certain conditions meaning i have an object type with some properties and I want to define a utility type that can conditionally enforce the presence of these properties based on the values of other properties
Here is the type definition:
export type User = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email?: string;
  phoneNumber?: string;
  contactPreference: 'email' | 'phone';
};

Now i want to create a type ConditionalRequired which makes sure that

if contactPreference is email, then email is required
if contactPreference is phone, then phone is required

Example:
// happy flow
const user1: ConditionalRequired<User> = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'foo',
  contactPreference: 'email',
  email: 'foobar@gmail.com', // here email is required
};

// Here it should cause type error because email is missing
const user2: ConditionalRequired<User> = {
  id: '2',
  name: 'foo2',
  contactPreference: 'email',
};

// Here it should cause type error because phone is missing
const user3: ConditionalRequired<User> = {
  id: '3',
  name: 'foo3',
  contactPreference: 'phone',
};


This is my unsuccessful attempt to achieve this:
type ConditionalRequired<T> = T & {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends 'email' ? { email: string } :
                 T[K] extends 'phone' ? { phoneNumber: string } : {};
};



Conditional types aren't what you're looking for. Nor does it look like a utility type like ConditionalRequired<T> is warranted since you're only passing in User as a type argument.  Really you want is a single ConditionallyRequiredUser type which is a union, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

this is perfect! the union seems to be a simple solution to what I was looking for. @jcalz please write the answer and I will mark it as accepted, thanks:)

The use case you're describing would be best served by a union type and not a conditional type.
You want to say that your user objects should have either an "email" contactPreference and a required email property, or a "phone" contactPreference and a required phoneNumber property.  That "either-or" relationship is what unions do.
In your case, we can represent the two possibilities as their own subtypes of User:
interface EmailPreferredUser extends User {
  contactPreference: 'email',
  email: string;
}

interface PhonePreferredUser extends User {
  contactPreference: 'phone',
  phoneNumber: string;
}

And then your desired type is the union of them:
export type ConditionallyRequiredUser =
  EmailPreferredUser | PhonePreferredUser

Note that I didn't write a ConditionalRequired<T> utility type, since it's not clear that such a thing is useful.  If the implementation needs to know about phone and email then it's not general enough to be reusable.  Your example only used ConditionalRequired<User>.
Okay, let's test it:
const user1: ConditionallyRequiredUser = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'foo',
  contactPreference: 'email',
  email: 'foobar@gmail.com', 
}; // okay

const user2: ConditionallyRequiredUser = { // error!
//    ~~~~~ <-- Property 'email' is missing
  id: '2',
  name: 'foo2',
  contactPreference: 'email',
};

const user3: ConditionallyRequiredUser = { // error!
//    ~~~~~
// Property 'phoneNumber' is missing 
  id: '3',
  name: 'foo3',
  contactPreference: 'phone',
};

Looks good. It behaves as desired in both the good and bad cases.
Playground link to code
